# How to get source code directory in Gradle plugin?

Tags: gradle

I want to get the directory of Java files in a Groovy plugin.

For example, I have a Java file in a directory:

```
"/gradleProject/src/main/java/com/file.java"
```

How can I get:

```
"src/main/java"
```

In Maven there is `Build.getSourceDirectory()`, what is the equivalent in Gradle?

Answer (score 7):

Further to Rene's answer, the groovy DSL makes it easy to get the `SourceSet`

```
SourceSet mainSourceSet = project.sourceSets.main
```

In java this is a little bit more verbose

```
SourceSet mainSourceSet = project.getConvention().getPlugin(JavaPluginConvention.class).getSourceSets().getByName("main");
```

Comment: This solution does not work anymore, do you know what is required to migrate this for gradle 6.0?

Comment: @rekire With Gradle 6 you can use ``project.convention.getPlugin(JavaPluginConvention).sourceSets.main.java``

Answer (score 3):

In Gradle, those source folders are managed by `SourceSet`s, that are brought to you by the Java plugin. The java plugin adds two sourceSets named `main` and `test`.

once the java plugin is applied, you can access those sourceSets and their properties (e.g. the folders you're looking) simply by name: `project.sourceSets.main.srcDirs` - this will give you all the configured source directories for the main sourceSet in your project.

Answer (score 2):

The latest way to do this, using the Kotlin DSL:

```kotlin
val javaExt = project.extensions.getByType(JavaPluginExtension::class.java)
val mainJavaSource = javaExt.sourceSets.getByName(SourceSet.MAIN_SOURCE_SET_NAME)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Kotlin DSL (Gradle 7.5)

```
tasks.register<JacocoReport>("jacocoTestReport") {
        dependsOn("testDebugUnitTest")
        val sourceSets = project.extensions.getByType<KotlinProjectExtension>().sourceSets
        sourceDirectories.setFrom(sourceSets)
    }
```

Note that besides the `JavaPluginExtension` there is also a `KotlinAndroidProjectExtension`, so you may can get rid of the Android Gradle Plugin in your community plugins.

Comment: I could not find KotlinProjectExtension. Do you know what could I miss?

Comment: It looks like I'm not using it any longer. But I could find that it is in the ` org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl` package, so I suspect it comes with the "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:x.y.z" at least at that time.

If you're *not* building an Android project and its about coverage, have a look here https://github.com/jjohannes/understanding-gradle/tree/main/21_Test_and_Code_Coverage_Reporting